# How do i pull out certain data from this json response?

Tags: python, json

Here is the link im opening in python:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/json/1.2.3.4').read()

print(response)
```

After printing the response it gives the result:

```
b'{"ip":"1.2.3.4","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"WA","region_name":"Washington","city":"Mukilteo","zip_code":"98275","time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","latitude":47.913,"longitude":-122.305,"metro_code":819}\n'
```

My question is, how can i print just the region name? i have this code so far:

```
import json
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/json/1.2.3.4').read()
print(response)
result = json.loads(response.decode('utf8'))
```

Its the last bit of pulling out the specific piece of data im stuck on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result object returned from json.loads will be a dictionary, so you can print the value like so:

```
print result['region_name']
```

Or even better, a bit more defensively, in the event that key doesn't exist:

```
print result.get('region_name', 'No region specified')
```

Also note that your urllib call should be:

```
response = urllib.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/json/1.2.3.4').read()
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you'd be able to access it as you would a python object:

```
result['region_code']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ast.literal_eval:

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_dict = ast.literal_eval(response.strip())
>>> my_dict['region_name']
'Washington'
```